# why jenkins could not start java process after building

Tags: java, jenkins

I am using this shell script to start java process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# 当使用未初始化的变量时，程序自动退出
# 也可以使用命令 set -o nounset
set -u

# 当任何一行命令执行失败时，自动退出脚本
# 也可以使用命令 set -o errexit
set -e

set -x


JAVA_HOME="/usr"
APP_HOME="/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/soa-robot/soa-robot-service/build/libs"
APP_NAME="soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

PID=`ps -ef|grep -w ${APP_NAME}|grep -v grep|cut -c 9-15`
if [[ ${PID} -gt 1 ]]; then
        kill -9 ${PID}
        sleep 5
else
        echo "Process not found"
fi

count=`ps -ef | grep ${APP_NAME} | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
if [[ ${count} -lt 1 ]]; then
  cd ${APP_HOME}
  nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx440M -Xms128M -jar \
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt \
  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5009 \
  ${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME} >> /dev/null &
  sleep 5
else
  echo "process aready exists!"
  exit 1
fi
```

and execute this script in jenkins like this:

```
/bin/bash ${WORKSPACE}/script/upgrade.sh
```

this is the jenkins execute log output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
37 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 29 up-to-date
+ /bin/bash /Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/soa-robot/script/upgrade.sh
+ JAVA_HOME=/usr
+ APP_HOME=/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/soa-robot/soa-robot-service/build/libs/
+ APP_NAME=soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
++ ps -ef
++ grep -w soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
++ grep -v grep
++ cut -c 9-15
+ PID=
+ [[ '' -gt 1 ]]
+ echo 'Process not found'
Process not found
++ ps -ef
++ grep soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
++ grep -v grep
++ wc -l
+ count='       0'
+ [[        0 -lt 1 ]]
+ cd /Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/soa-robot/soa-robot-service/build/libs/
+ sleep 5
+ nohup /usr/bin/java -Xmx440M -Xms128M -jar -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5009 /Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/soa-robot/soa-robot-service/build/libs/soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Process leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information
Finished: SUCCESS
```

but when I login the server and find the process is not started, why would this happen? When I execute this script in server's terminal,it could start process success:

```
nohup /usr/bin/java -Xmx440M -Xms128M -jar -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5009 /Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/workspace/soa-robot/soa-robot-service/build/libs//soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

Comment: did you put `+ nohup /usr/bin/java -Xmx440M -Xms128M -jar ....  &` & at the end of command ?

Comment: The SUCCESS message is about the script itself, not the java command invoked.

Comment: Yes,I add & in the command's last @ThanhNguyenVan